# jQuery child element selector not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<page size="A4" id="Invoice_1">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="odd">
                <td class="first" style="padding-right: 1px;text-align: left;min-width: 29px;padding-left: 5px">Sr.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="odd data_row">
                <td class="first data" style="min-width: 29px;">4</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</page>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#Invoice_1 > table > tbody > tr > .data_row:last').length
```

Anyone can please tell me hy this is not working? How can I make it workable?

Comment: `.data_row` is class defined for `TR`, so use `$('#Invoice_1 > table > tbody > tr.data_row:last').length`,

Comment: @Satpal `$('#Invoice_1 > table > tbody > tr.data_row:last').length` will always return **1** since you are only looking at the length of number of **last rows** which is by definition can only be one.

Comment: Right selector will depend a lot on - *Whose length are you looking to find out?* Please update your question to specify the same.

Answer (score 2):

`.data_row` is not a child of `tr`, it's the `tr` itself

So the correct selector would be

```
$('#Invoice_1 > table > tbody > tr.data_row:last')
```

Or, in this case it would be enough to do

```
$('#Invoice_1 tr.data_row:last')
```

Answer (score 0):

> Anyone can please tell me Why this is a not working?

No `tr` has a child element with class `.data_row`.

In fact `.data-row` is the class of `tr` itself.

> How can I make it workable?

You haven't mentioned whose length you want to fetch, so **Perhaps**

```
$('#Invoice_1 > table > tbody > tr.data_row:last > td').length
```

**Assuming that you want to fetch the number of `td` elements in last row**.